# MariaDB Cluster - One node slower than others

Tags: mysql, performance, centos6, mariadb

I have a MariaDB Cluster (x3) in Master/Master replication.

Every server have the same my.cnf, and exact same resources.

But one of them is 2 time slower than the two others, and i can't figure out why...

Does someone have a clue ?

my.cnf:

```
[client-server]

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d


[mariadb]
log-error=/var/log/mysql.log

[mysqld]
#1. Mandatory settings: these settings are REQUIRED for proper cluster operation
query_cache_size=0
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
# innodb_doublewrite=1 - this is the default and it should stay this way

# 2. Optional mysqld settings: your regular InnoDB tuning and such
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
innodb_buffer_pool_size=500M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
max_connections = 50
thread_cache_size = 10
skip-name-resolve

# 3. wsrep provider configuration: basic wsrep options
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=3G"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.5.1,192.168.5.2,192.168.5.3"
wsrep_cluster_name='xxx_galera'
wsrep_node_address='192.168.5.2'
wsrep_node_name='node2'
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup
wsrep_sst_auth=root:xxxxxxxx

# 4. additional "frequently used" wsrep settings
wsrep_slave_threads=2           #Max = 1/cpu
```

Thanks

(Sorry for my english)

UPDATE 1:

- I see it's slow because i have an app which is doing some requests on databases (with loadbalancing). When it comes to db2, it takes twice more time (18 to 26s instead of 11s)
  When the exact same request is executed by another node, it's ok.
  When i shutdown this database, no more problem (with only 2 in loadbalancing)
- All databases have their own storage, the same resources, and the same connection (200 mbps).
- They are virtual machines hosted by Gandi.net, they use Xen.

UPDATE 2:

I just migrated the drive to another server, same results...
So it's not a hardware problem

Comment: How you measure performance?

Comment: I have a website making multiple requests, and each time db2 is used, it takes twice more time

Comment: The network connection is the same to all nodes?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same, all are VMs with a 200mb interface

Comment: Which technology you using for visualization? On VMware you can check the real resourses that a server occupies. Are all hosted on the same host? what about mount points, all refer to same storage?

Comment: Actually it's a Cloud storage (IaaS), so i don't have a full access to this information. Indeed, it could be a hardware problem, but i'll keep that in case i don't find anything else, because i'll have to create a new VM and reconfigure everything. Thanks for the help by the way :)